# how to Interface with Olympus Chemistry Analyzer

Tags: data-transfer

I have a MIS system which collects and stores patient test orders in the database. Now my customer is requiring to connect the system with Olympus Chemistry Analyzer (AU5400 model) so that the analyzer can read all tests from my MIS database and return results of all given tests. The problem is I don't know how to communicate with the chemistry analyzer. Please let me know how I can transfer data between the two systems. I've googled a lot but still no luck for a perfect solution.

Comment: are there any network ports on it?

Comment: yes, there is a computer connected with that machine. But I don't know how it exports data or in which format I should give it feed data from my system.

Comment: i have no clue how the networking works as the manual said nothing about it

Comment: do they recognize each other

Comment: Yes they are connected and that computer is provided by the Olympus authority to enter tests manually but I wanted to send data to that computer from my MIS database.

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless we hack into the Olympus computer on the chem analyzer; i am not the person to ask, go find a black hat.